# Django model returning values in the wrong columns

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

This is just weird.

I create an instance of a django model and save it to the database, but when I recall it again the values are in the wrong columns.  I tried moving the code over to another machine, thinking I might have some library misconfiguration, but it failed there, also.  I did some extensive google searching, but did not find any problem similar to mine.

Here is the model definition: (with `__init__` defined, if that matters)

```
class Buffer(models.Model):
    b_bname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    b_tdate = models.DateField() # date of transaction
    b_bdate = models.DateField() # date at bank
    b_bamnt = models.FloatField()
    b_descript = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    b_kind = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    b_account = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Buffer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.b_bname = name
```

Here is an example of the failure:

```
% python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  4 2012, 18:36:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 20070831 patched [FreeBSD]] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from buffer.models import Buffer
>>> b = Buffer('schwab')
>>> b.b_tdate = '2008-11-03'
>>> b.b_bdate = '2009-01-20'
>>> b.b_bamnt = 3.1415
>>> b.b_descript = 'easy as pi'
>>> b.b_kind = 'POS'
>>> b.b_account = 'groceries'
>>> b.save()
(0.002) INSERT INTO "buffer_buffer" ("b_bname", "b_tdate", "b_bdate", "b_bamnt", "b_descript", "b_kind", "b_account") VALUES (schwab, 2008-11-03, 2009-01-20, 3.1415, easy as pi, POS, groceries); args=['schwab', u'2008-11-03', u'2009-01-20', 3.1415, 'easy as pi', 'POS', 'groceries']
(0.002) INSERT INTO "buffer_buffer" ("b_bname", "b_tdate", "b_bdate", "b_bamnt", "b_descript", "b_kind", "b_account") VALUES (schwab, 2008-11-03, 2009-01-20, 3.1415, easy as pi, POS, groceries); args=['schwab', u'2008-11-03', u'2009-01-20', 3.1415, 'easy as pi', 'POS', 'groceries']
>>> b.pk                  
1
>>> c = Buffer.objects.get(pk=1)
(0.000) SELECT "buffer_buffer"."id", "buffer_buffer"."b_bname", "buffer_buffer"."b_tdate", "buffer_buffer"."b_bdate", "buffer_buffer"."b_bamnt", "buffer_buffer"."b_descript", "buffer_buffer"."b_kind", "buffer_buffer"."b_account" FROM "buffer_buffer" WHERE "buffer_buffer"."id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
(0.000) SELECT "buffer_buffer"."id", "buffer_buffer"."b_bname", "buffer_buffer"."b_tdate", "buffer_buffer"."b_bdate", "buffer_buffer"."b_bamnt", "buffer_buffer"."b_descript", "buffer_buffer"."b_kind", "buffer_buffer"."b_account" FROM "buffer_buffer" WHERE "buffer_buffer"."id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
>>> c.b_bname
1
>>> c.b_tdate
datetime.date(2009, 1, 20)
>>> c.b_bdate
3.1415
>>> c.b_bamnt
u'easy as pi'
>>> c.b_kind
u'groceries'
>>> c.b_account
''
>>> 
% sqlite3 register 
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select count(id) from buffer_buffer;
1
sqlite> select b_bamnt from buffer_buffer;
3.1415
```

As you can see, the database is correct, but the retrieved object is wrong.  Where have I messed up?  I must have a bug here somewhere.  I have been hunting it for over a day, now.

Environment: Python 2.7, Django 1.4, sqlite 3.7 as the backend, FreeBSD 9.0

Comment: Everything looks right. Just try Moving `self.b_bname = name` above `super()`

Comment: Moving the assignment earlier did not change the outcome.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change the type signature of the model’s `__init__` method to take a `name` argument. It is called not only when you create an instance in the shell, but whenever else an instance is initialised, including when you fetch from the db.

It isn't clear why you need to to override the `__init__` method, when you can use named arguments as follows:

> > > b = Buffer(name='schwab')

If you want a convenience method for when you creating new instances, consider creating a custom manager with a create method. Look at the [`User.objects.create_user()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L171) method for example, which takes care of hashing the password.